# Player sliding while standing still

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote this code for player movement:

```
public float gravity = -9.8f;
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
movement.y = gravity;
```

The **gravity** variable is supposed to keep the Player to the ground but the problem is that it also slowly slides the player around the terrain.

Comment: why don't you use a `Rigidbody` instead ?

Comment: Agreed, you probably should leave the physics to the physics engine. If you really insist on doing it this way then we'd need a little more info on what's going on. Sliding in which direction? What have you tried to fix, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting **Horizontal Only** look to the Player and **Vertical Only** look to the Camera in the Unity Editor solves the problem.